# What is wrong with this code? Request for permissions not appearing Android Studio

Tags: java, android, python-requests, geolocation, location

This code is suppose to connect to an android phone and the Logcat should receive the lat and lng of the device. However the phone doesn't receive the notification for permissions. There are no errors appearing on the console so I'm unsure of what is wrong.

Location class

```
package com.example.code;

import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.IBinder;

import android.os.Looper;
import android.util.Log;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;

import com.google.android.gms.location.FusedLocationProviderClient;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationResult;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;

import java.util.Objects;

public class location extends Service {
    FusedLocationProviderClient fusedLocationProviderClient;
    LocationCallback locationCallback;

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        fusedLocationProviderClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this);
        locationCallback = new LocationCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onLocationResult(LocationResult locationResult) {
                super.onLocationResult(locationResult);
                Log.d("mylog", "Lat:" + locationResult.getLastLocation().getLatitude()
                        + "," + "lng:" + locationResult.getLastLocation().getLongitude());
            }
        };
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        requestLocation();
        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }

    private void requestLocation() {
        try {
            LocationRequest locationRequest = new LocationRequest();
            locationRequest.setInterval(5000);
            locationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY);

            fusedLocationProviderClient.requestLocationUpdates(
                    locationRequest,
                    locationCallback,
                    Looper.myLooper()
            );
        } catch (SecurityException e) {
            // Handle location permission issues or other security-related errors
            Log.e("mylog", "Error requesting location updates: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}

---
```

locationService class

```
package com.example.code;

import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.IBinder;

import androidx.annotation.Nullable;

public class locationService extends Service {

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

}
```

Main class

```
package com.example.code;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Toast;
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import com.google.android.gms.location.FusedLocationProviderClient;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat;

public class Main extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final int LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE = 1;
    private FusedLocationProviderClient fusedLocationProviderClient;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
            } else {
                startService();
            }
        } else {
            startService();
        }
    }
    void startService() {
        Intent intent = new Intent( Main.this, LocationServices.class);
        startService(intent);

    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        if (requestCode == LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE) {
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                startService();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Please give location permissions", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I tried to make sure the xml file had the right permissions and services

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

```
<service android:name=".location"
            android:foregroundServiceType="location"
            />
```

and made sure to add
`implementation ("com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:21.2.0")`

But the result remains the same